# Time complexity for a recursion inside for loop java

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, permutation

Hello i encountered this problem. I try to solve this for three days now with the help of several stack overflow posts, google and youtube but i can´t solve this.

My Question is. How do i get T(N) = ? for perm(1). I guess it is somehow O(n^2) or even worse because of the following. My for-loop depends on a variable n and my recursion inside takes n+1 so this would be n*(n+1) ~ n^2. But how do i get through this program and proove this? I know i can ignore all constant factors  like addition etc but i would be nice if someone takes the time to explain every time-unit-cost what ever in the code and sum it up until we have a recursiv equation.

To get every single permutation we change perm(1) to perm(0).
**1) How many calls do we have if we permute n-Numbers
2) How many calls are being omitted in average for a single permutation if n gets very big.**

Explanation. We give this program n-Numbers to permute. If we want to permute the 0 as well, we call perm(0), else we call perm(1).

```
private void perm(int i) { // permute from index i; 1 or 0(all permuts).
    if (i >= max) put();  // one permutation finished, max = n-1
    else {
        for (int j = i; j <= max; j++) { // everyone in front
            swap(i, j);               // swap
            perm(i + 1);               // and recursion
        }
        int h = a[i];                 // restore Array
        System.arraycopy(a, i + 1, a, i, max - i); // shift left
        a[max] = h;
    }
} // end perm

private void swap(int i, int j) {   // swap a[i] <-> a[j]
    if (i != j) {
        int h = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = h;
    }
} // end swap

private synchronized void put() {   // give over to array
    mayread = true;                 // read a (array)
    notify();                      // notify the other Thread
    try {
        if (a != null)
            while (mayread) wait();    // non busy waiting
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
} // end put
```

And my final question. What the heck happens when we are inside the for-loop and we call swap(1,1), as j=i, or swap(2,2) and after that the recursion.

Answer (score 3):

`swap` is O(1).

`perm` executes a loop of `max-i+1` iterations, then, on each iteration executes `perm(i+1)`. Then, after all, it does an arraycopy of `max-i` items.

Let's call `max` as `n`.

- `perm(1)` executes the loop `n` times
- `perm(2)` executes the loop `n-1` times
- `perm(3)` executes the loop `n-2` times

and so on...

This leads to a `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1` iterations. `O(n!)`

Also, `swap(1, 1)` does nothing.

Comment: Thank you the part (n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3) --> O((n-1)!) is new to me and i will google for it now but it sounds like what i needed. Thank you for you explanation and i know that swap(1,1) does nothing but when does it do sth. How do we get to swap(2,1) or swap(1,2). Thanks

Comment: @MatthisKohli What do you mean? `swap(2, 1)` will never happen, because `j>=i` always. But `swap(1, 2)` will swap the values of the positions `1` and `2` of the array `a`. Also, please note I fixed my answer, it is O(n!). I didn't consider the `<=` in the for loop.

Comment: I mean: How does the algorithm swap values. It starts with i=1 and sets j=i, so swap(1,1) will do nothing, then we call the recursion and the same happens for perm(i+1), so i = 2 and j = i, so swap(2,2) and again we call recursion perm(i+1), so i = 3 and j = i , so swap(3,3) nothing, if our N was 5, we call perm(i+1), so i = 4 and j = i and MAX is 5-1, so we have j <= 4 true. What happens to the for loop meanwhile and when do we get to swap(1,2). I dont understand this part.